# Unexpected behaviour when inheriting constructors with using keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to inherit constructors from the base class and define an additional constructor in the derived class.

```
#include <iostream>

#define BREAK_THIS_CODE 1

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base " << "\n";
    }

    Base(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Base " << i << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;

#if BREAK_THIS_CODE
    Derived(int i, int j)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived " << i << " " << j << "\n";
    }
#endif
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1(10);
    Derived d2; // error C2512: 'Derived': no appropriate default constructor available

    return 0;
}
```

Adding `Derived(int, int)` seems to delete `Base()` but `Base(int)` is unaffected by this. Why is the default constructor getting removed? I expected `Derived` to have a total of three user-defined constructors. The only thing I can think of is the inherited `Base()` constructor is being treated as an implicitly-declared default constructor and adding an extra constructor is deleting the default constructor.

I've tried this on VS2015 and get the following error:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(37): error C2512: 'Derived': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  main.cpp(19): note: see declaration of 'Derived'
```

Also tried this example on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/790b540c44dccb9f

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O3 -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:35:10: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Derived'
        Derived d2;
                ^
main.cpp:22:14: note: candidate constructor (inherited) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
        using Base::Base;
                    ^
main.cpp:13:2: note: inherited from here
        Base(int i)
        ^
main.cpp:19:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class Derived : public Base
      ^
main.cpp:19:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
main.cpp:25:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
        Derived(int i, int j)
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: IIRC, You cannot inherit the default constructor using the `using Base::Base;` declaration. You can inherit all other constructors.

Comment: If I remove `Derived(int, int)` and run the program, `Derived d2;` appears to call `Base::Base` although on second thought that's because the implicit `Derived::Derived` is calling `Base::Base`?

Comment: I think that's correct.

Comment: `Derived() = default;` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

> If the *using-declaration* refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. using `Base::Base;`), constructors of that base class are inherited, according to the following rules:
>
> 1) A set of candidate inheriting constructors is composed of
>
> [rules here]
>
> 2) All candidate inherited constructors **that aren't the default constructor or the copy/move constructor** and whose signatures do not match user-defined constructors in the derived class, are implicitly declared in the derived class. The default parameters are not inherited

So you cannot inherit a default constructor.  When a class has declared a user-defined constructor, the compiler does not generate a default constructor for that class, unless you explicitly ask for one using `Derived() = default`.  When you remove your user-defined constructor, the compiler can then generate a default constructor for you.